# Use function only once

Tags: javascript

Quick question here. I tried to make this function work only once but it keeps getting called. How am I supposed to tell it to stop working after it executed the first time?

```
function axis_y_superior_inferior() {
    if ((y_actual <= y_final) && (y_actual >= y_final)) {
        var slop = (y_actual) / (x_actual);
        var crossing_point = ((y_actual - y_final)/slop) + x_actual;

        if ((slop > (x_origen - dimension_x)) && (crossing_point < x_final)) {
            y_actual = y_final - y_actual;                          
            y_actual = y_final + y_actual;
            vectory = 0 - vectory;
            document.getElementById("block").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What "keeps looping" means? There are no any loops in this function.

Comment: ...don't call it more than once? This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Could you show the part that actually contains the loop?

Comment: There is no loop as far as i can see. Where do you call that function? Add some code pls.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be looping, there's no loop block.  It must be being called multiple times from somewhere else.

If you want it to only run once, make a global variable outside of the function (eg var axis_y_superior_inferior_ran = false) and set it to true at the end of the function.  At the beginning of the function, check the variable and return if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

The function is going to be run every time it is called.  The best way to make sure it is run once is to ensure it only is called once.  You haven't provided the context in which it is called, so we have no way of figuring out why it gets executed multiple times.

You can make your function only run only once regardless of how many times it is called by having a variable keep track of every time it is called. You can avoid taking up the global namespace with said variable by wrapping it in a closure:

```
function runOnlyNTimes(f, n) {
    var calls = 0;
    return (function() {
        calls++;
        if (calls <= n) {
            f.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
}

function axis_y_superior_inferior() {
    if ((y_actual <= y_final) && (y_actual >= y_final)) {
        var slop = (y_actual) / (x_actual);
        var crossing_point = ((y_actual - y_final)/slop) + x_actual;

        if ((slop > (x_origen - dimension_x)) && (crossing_point < x_final)) {
            y_actual = y_final - y_actual;                          
            y_actual = y_final + y_actual;
            vectory = 0 - vectory;
            document.getElementById("block").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

axis_y_superior_inferior = runOnlyNTimes(axis_y_superior_inferior, 1);
```

However, I would only recommend this for cases in which you don't have control over how many times the function was called for whatever reason.